# Cross-device tracking with Google Signals and user reporting in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4, cross-device

I'm a bit confused on how activating the use of Google Signals in GA4 affects the reporting and raw data. One thing that is obvious is that after activation the demographics data becomes available (gender, age, interests) inside GA. But what about cross-device users stitching?

On the net I saw a couple of articles which have mentioned that turning Google Signals on would affect the overall number of users in the reports (basically reduce it by identifying one user across several devices when it is possible). Does it mean that there will be cross-device users stitched under one Google Client IDs (cid)? Exploring the device overlap I could see a small segment of such users in user explorer who were registered from different devices and have same Client ID on both devices.

This also means that these joint cross-device users data would actually be exported to Google BigQuery, right? By data I mean that we would see this same cross-device user under one and same Client ID in Bigquery.

**Bonus question:**
How does Google Client ID is actually persisted from the previous device? Does GA4 Configuration Tag sends a dedicated request to Google server on first page load to check if there is user data (Client ID) available from other devices and assigns an old cid to this new visit if match is found in the database?

Or would we see a new cid in real time, but it would be replaced later with the cid from other device when Google renders and aggregates the data on the server side before pushing it into our GA4 account reports?

* we are not currently using any internal User ID of our own to track users across devices

Comment: Checking the documentation its possible to see that when you activate google signals [bigquery export](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7532985?hl=en#:~:text=Additional%20data%20collected%20by%20Google%20signals%20is%20not%20exported%20to%20BigQuery.) and [cross device](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7532985?hl=en#:~:text=You%20cannot%20yet%20apply%20segments%20to%20the%20Cross%20Device%20reports.) are not supported features.

Comment: @ewertonvsilva, yeah, I saw this. But I see some cross-device users in the User Explorer inside a Free Form exploration under one stitched cid. If there is no export of such cross-device matched data to BigQuery that would mean that one cross-device user would become several with different client ids. And that leads to inconsistency of data between GA data and the GA data exported to BQ. Which is not the case with UA properties I think, where you could match each user between the GA and BQ. Anyway, we will connect the BQ to our GA4 soon and check how such cross-device users are exported.